# Big O Notation - Orders of Magnitude

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I am currently trying to work out what are the main quantitative differences between a quadratic algorithm, a cubic algorithm and one which is exponential.

What I don't understand is what it means by "Quantitative" and what it really is asking? I tried searching for information on this but no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: Show the approximate corresponding values for n = 1,2, 4, 10 and 20 in a  table showing the order of magnitude for an O(n2), O(n3) and an O(2n). What would be the corresponding values?

Comment: maybe better trying http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ here is a little OT

Comment: Simply draw a table, with n^2, n^3 and 2^n as the columns, and increasing n for every row. Then fill in the values and see what order of magnitude they are (http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_magnitude)

Comment: So for example, n = 2. 
n^2 = 4,
n^3 = 8,
2^n = 4

Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. now do it for n = 1,2, 4, 10, 20.

Comment: @FelicePollano: cstheory is for research level computer science, cs.stackexchange.com would be more suitable for this, but I think stackoverflow is fine for this level of question.

Comment: @HåvardGeithus Ok I think I got it now! Just one last thing which I don't understand. For example - for N = 2, both n^2 and 2^n give the same answer but for n = 8 for example its different. How do you work out 2^n for a value?

Comment: n^2 = n * n, but 2^n is 2*2*2 ... and so on, n times. If you don't have a calculator at hand, simply input for example 2^10 at google ;)

Comment: @PeterAlexander agree sorry I point the wrong site I would vote fro cs too

Comment: You're welcome. And by the way http://www.khanacademy.org/ is a great resource for improving your mathematical intuition :) At least that's my experience (there are also many other interesting topics covered there)

Comment: `How do you work out 2^n for a value?` Can I ask what your education is? It seems like you're in a little over your head.

Answer (score 3):

When you use big-O notation to estimate the computational complexity of an algorithm,
the goal is to provide a *qualitative* insight as to how changes in *N* affect the algorithmic
performance as *N* becomes large.

If you eliminate any term whose contribution to the total ceases to be significant as *N* becomes large and eliminate any constant factors, I guess you could say you are left with the main *quantitative* difference.

Answer (score 2):

Quantitative differences just means differences in quantity -- i.e. what are the size differences between those different kinds of algorithms? It would be good idea to give numeric examples, e.g. show the running time of quadratic, cubic, and exponential algorithms for some example problem sizes.

Comment: For example if I were to use values, n = 1 2 4 10 and 20. How would I calculate the problem sizes from those values?

Comment: @user1028145: n is the problem size. For quadratic problems, the run time is n * n, for cubic it's n * n * n, and for exponential it is e ^ n.

Comment: It can be any number, k. Not just e, which usually means ca. 2,71828